# PHP byte sequence of integers on big endian hardware

Tags: php

If I were to run this PHP code on a "big endian" machine, what would I get?

```
$v = 0x12345678;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 4 ; $i++) {
    echo "$i: " . dechex(($v>>($i*8))&0xff) . "\n";
}
```

would it be "A":

```
0: 78
1: 56
2: 34
3: 12
```

or would it be "B":

```
0: 12
1: 34
2: 56
3: 78
```

I'm asking as while desktop computers are just about always little endian, and PHP always uses the hardware's representation internally (one of it's most problematic shortcomings really) it still prints out "A" which is essentially big endian from what I remember.

Comment: *what would I get?* Why not just try it?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't have both little and big endian machine?

Comment: Exactly @Med I only have my Desktop, which is little endian.

Comment: It was just pointed out to me on Google+, that the code should always deliver the first sequence, as $v>>($i*8) is essentially dividing the number ($i*256), and thus ignores the underlying structures.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I donot have Big endian machine to test it.
Burt based upon the theory, If we layout $v = 0x12345678; in memory
then in littel endian it becomes:

byte0:78
byte1:56
byte2:34
byte3:12

But In big endian it becomes:

byte0:12 byte1:34 byte2:56 byte3:78

So you should see A on little endian and B on big endian.

Moreover if you want to simulate the bigendian behaviour, you can just try htons function which converts short number from host architecture to network byte order and that is always big endian.

Comment: htons is not a PHP function, PHP provides a function called pack that can do the same. 
But as I mentioned in a comment above, I think I'm short circuiting my own question, as I'm not actually looking at the memory. Regardless of the underlying architecture, the code I provided will always return "A", as I'm essentially dividing by 256 and mask the low byte.